# How to use MongoVUE on Dreamhost VPS?

Tags: mongodb, dreamhost

I contacted Dreamhost support but they refuse to help with setting up of third party softwares. And, there are little traffic on the official user forums: I asked support questions on 3 occasions on the forums and got 0 replies each time.

**Question**

I am trying to connect to MongoDB on my Dreamhost VPS. What do I input in MongoVUE for the entry "Server"? Do I have to set up a SSH Tunnel?

Is there an easier alternative to having a GUI for MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoVUE (or any other [admin UI](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs)) connects via the MongoDB server port, which by default is 27017.  Assuming you don't have a firewall or [`bind_ip`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration) configuration restriction blocking access to the MongoDB port, you should be able to connect directly from MongoVUE using your server name as the host.

It would be a *much* better idea to connect using an SSH tunnel with port forwarding rather than having your database server port available directly.

Other options for limiting access include:

- [firewall restrictions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-SecuringtheNetwork) .. ideally your home or remote network has a fixed IP address that could be used to limit access
- [user authentication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-RunninginSecureMode%28with%5Cauthor%5CkeyFile%29) .. restrict access per database (either read only or read/write)
- Instead of using a desktop UI like MongoVUE, you could install one of the web-based admin UIs such as [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo).  In this case you could configure the admin UI on the server talking to localhost:27017, and would not have to open up external access to the MongoDB server.  For additional security you can use standard web server controls such as password authentication and SSL.

> Is there an easier alternative to having a GUI for MongoDB?

It would be worth familiarizing your self with the [`mongo` interactive shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell).  There is some functionality you can use in the shell, such as JavaScript functions, that may not be available in Admin UIs.  As a bonus you'll also learn a bit more about syntax and queries that would be helpful for a developer.  This does depend on you having some comfort level on using a command-line interface, though.

Comment: Hmmm...I was hoping for some advice that is directly related to Dreamhost.

Comment: @Legendre: Do you want to add some more details on your Dreamhost VPS setup (O/S version, how you installed MongoDB, ...?).  Assuming you're running a default Dreamhost VPS with Debian, and have installed the default Debian MongoDB package .. the MongoDB config is likely set with `bind_ip` to 127.0.0.1 so you'd need to use port forwarding.  The configuration needed should be more specific to the O/S and install packages than Dreamhost.

Comment: Default Dreamhost VPS with Debian. I "activated" MongoDB via the web panel. I am sorry but I am quite new to server side stuff. Would you say the mongo interactive shell is sufficient? i.e. Do I even need a GUI? Sounds like setting up a GUI is quite a bit of work. Thanks!

Comment: GUI is really a matter of preference. I find it more instructive to learn how to use the command line tools, and there may be some newer features that you could access directly without a GUI equivalent. Conversely, a good GUI may save you some reading up on options and provide some features that aren't part of the server :). If you are confortable having a peek in `ssh` I would try logging into your server and running `mongo` (which should connect to the local DB).  `help` gives you a list of commands.

Comment: You should also be able to use `getCommandLineOpts()` to see the current config options including `bind_ip` restriction (if set).  The bind_ip restriction limits the IP addresses that MongoDB listens to.  If this is set to `127.0.0.1` (or localhost) then you would definitely not be able to connect remotely.  If the `bind_ip` option isn't set and remote connections still appear to be blocked, you would have to check/adjust your firewall settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help! One last question: for the "Server" entry in MongoVUE, I should be entering something like "ps3857.dreamhost.com" (random example) right? Which refers to my VPS.

Comment: @Legendre: Yes, assuming you can connect to your mongod port remotely .. you can use the VPS hostname in the MongoVUE "Server" entry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extended Q&A! :)